# How to add Values into Json array to set equal array size

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to my all json array size is equal,suppose my array limit is 2, in my json many array have less or high json count than 2.if array object size less than 2 add empty array with null values and if greater than 2 remove.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUsers": [
      {
        "UserProfileDetail": {
          "UserStatus": {
            "name": "User One"
          },
          "UserStatusDate": "2018-10-31T06:12:42+00:00",
          "EnrollId": "am**********************************",
          "lastDate": "2019-07-22T03:05:39.0245313-04:00"
        },
        "UserInformation": {
          "Id": 1111122,
          "firstName": "*****",
          "middleName": null,
          "lastName": "*****",
          "otherNames": null,
          "primaryState": "MA",
          "otherState": [
            "MA",
            "BA",
            "DL",
            "RJ"
          ],
          "UserLicense": [
            {
              "licenseState": "MA",
              "licenseNumber": "000000000",
              "licenseStatus": null,
              "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa": "only one"
            },
            {
              "licenseState": "MA2",
              "licenseNumber": "0000000002",
              "licenseStatus": null,
              "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa": "only one2"
            },
            {
              "licenseState": "MA3",
              "licenseNumber": "0000000003",
              "licenseStatus": null,
              "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa": "only one3"
            }
          ],
          "UserLocation": [
            {
              "location": "DL",
              "SubrLocation": [
                {
                  "sub location1": "DL1",
                  "sub location2": "DL2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Setting": "ADMINISTRATIVE",
          "primaryEmail": "*****@*****.com",
          "modifiedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null
        }
      },
      {
        "UserProfileDetail": {
          "UserStatus": {
            "name": "User Two"
          },
          "UserStatusDate": "2019-10-31T06:12:42+00:00",
          "EnrollId": "am**********************************",
          "lastDate": "2019-07-22T03:05:39.0245313-04:00"
        },
        "UserInformation": {
          "Id": 443333,
          "firstName": "*****",
          "middleName": "Jhon",
          "lastName": "*****",
          "otherNames": null,
          "primaryState": "AK",
          "otherState": [
            "MP",
            "CLT"
          ],
          "UserLicense": [
            {
              "licenseState": "KL",
              "licenseNumber": "000000220",
              "licenseStatus": "Valid"
            }
          ],
          "UserLocation": [
            {
              "location": "KL",
              "SubrLocation": [
                {
                  "sub location1": "KL",
                  "sub location2": "KL2"
                },
                {
                  "sub location1": "TN",
                  "sub location2": "TN2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Setting": "ADMINISTRATIVE",
          "primaryEmail": "*****@*****.com",
          "modifiedAt": null,
          "createdAt": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above example following array object is found.
1.UserLicense
2.UserLocation
3.SubrLocation

The 'UserLicense' location in first json is 3 and second json is two. I want remove one from first json and add empty json to second. like this i want all json array (including nested json array object).
I know its not a correct requirement/method.
some body please help me

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to restrict the array size when the JSON is serialized, or do you want to restrict the array size when deserializing into an object? What keeps you from doing this programmatically? This should really be a matter of business logic, rather than serialization.

Comment: i have already serialized json. that json contains many arrays. i want each array size is same

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic question about working with json in .NET.

**Option 1**

You could create a class model that represents your json, then load it with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, then make the changes in the model and serialize it back to json with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

The top two elements would look like this:

```
public class TopElement
{
    [JsonProperty("data", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("getUsers", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public GetUsers[] GetUsers { get; set; }
}
// ... and so on
```

Deserialize json from string:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopElement>(jsonString);
```

**Option 2**

You could use directly `JObject` to load the json and then make changes in it.